# PC doesn't power up if RAM is placed in first slot

Tags: memory, motherboard, hardware-failure

I have a [Biostar H61MLV3 motherboard](http://www.biostar-usa.com/app/en-us/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=724#specification) with a Core i3 3220 and a 4GB DDR3 memoy module. Recently I have a lot of issue with this system. Running memtest showed memory problems.

I tried to reseating my memory (in the same slot) and moving it to another memory slot. But when the DIMM is placed in the first slot, the CPU fan runs, the motherboard beep is heard, but keyboard, mouse and monitor show no flash/change.

Memory: UDIMM, 4096 MBytes PC3-10700 (667 MHz), 1.50v
Motherboard: BIOSTAR Group, H61MLV3, rev 7.0

Comment: Not all motherboard support all memory in any slot. Some require a specific order of installation. E.g. if only one DIMM then it must be in slot X. What does your manual say about this? (Also, please add your motherboard to the post. Not just something from manufacturer Biostar). And mention if you have a spare DIMM or not. And if you have access to a second (known stable) system with the same memory type. Etc etc.

Comment: PC was running fine with RAM in first slot a few days back. Then it suddenly started behaving so. Also, I'm not a hardware expert. All I can tell about it is what's printed on the mobo's cover carton. It says intel chipset H61, DUAL DDR3-1600, PCIE GEN. 3 :-(

Comment: That is sadly as generic as '2.0 liter 4 stroke engine, leather seat covers'. It does not pin the model down. Try something like the mainboard tab from http://www.cpuid.com/downloads/cpu-z/cpu-z_1.80-en.exe (windows), or 'kenv' if you run FreeBSd, or .... many potential programs.

Comment: Yeah I just checked my models manual on their website. It does support 2 DIMM of DDR3 1600/1333/1066

Comment: "It's an assembled core i3 3.3 ghz cpu" - Can you be more specific.  There are literally 50 different i'3 CPUs that have been released in the last 6 years.  Please provide specific information about your i3 and edit your question.  You also need to provide more specifics about your motherboard and the memory you already had and the memory you purchased.  Please **edit** your question and include this information.  Without this information your question is way too broad to even be answered.